# How to bind size properties with a unit different than px?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, user-controls, units-of-measurement

The default unit for the size of every user control is px, but it is possible to easily set the size to a different unit, for instance:

```
<Canvas Height="29.7cm" Width="21cm" />
```

But what should I do if I want to bind these properties? How do I retain the information about my desired unit?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the approach described [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9508847/1834662)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) which converts the string representation to double (using [LengthConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.lengthconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(double))]
public class SizeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double size = (double)new LengthConverter().ConvertFrom(value.ToString());
        return size;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("SizeConverter is a oneway converter.")
    }
}
```

After that you can refer that converter from your XAML:

```
<src:SizeConverter x:Key="sizeConverter"/>

<Canvas Height="{Binding Path=Height, Converter={StaticResource sizeConverter}}" 
        Width="{Binding Path=Width, Converter={StaticResource sizeConverter}}" />
```

(Here `Height` and `Width` are `strings` available in the `DataContext` of your `Canvas`.)