# How the BarItem Indent interval is measured in Devexpress WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

In Devexpress docuemtnation for [BarItemVerticalIndent](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ToolBarControlBase.BarItemVerticalIndent) and [BarItemHorizontalIndent](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.ToolBarControlBase.BarItemHorizontalIndent), it is mentioned that the interval is a `Double`.
I tried to understand the referred unit of measurement in the documentation and online but I couldn't find it.

So, if the indent is 2, what does it mean? 2px, 2in, 2km ??
If it's a level like low-mid-high, how to figure out the equivalent of say 5px?

Any pointers to relevant documentation or clear resources are highly appreciated
thanks,
Katia

Comment: What does it look like when you set it to 2? If no particular unit is mentioned in the documentation, it's certainly the usual WPF device independent units/pixels, as used for Width, Height, Margin etc.

Comment: @Clemens bar items will be spaced out more than if it's 0. In margins which use `Thinkness`, it is possible to specify the unit as px, in, cm, or pt.

Comment: That is supported by the XAML Parser. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508847/1136211. Try if it also works for the BarItem properties.

Comment: @Katia, for DevExpress related questions, you can use their support. I am sure, you will get a detailed answer: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the link, I will look more into that and update you :)